# Can advice be used in non-reply end point

Tags: spring-integration

I want to use advice to do some retry logic in outbound adapter say ftp outbound adapter, however when I study "Spring integration Reference Manual", I found  advice can only be used in reply-producing-endpoint, is that true?

If my understanding is correct, how can I do retry after outbound adapter failed?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found advice can only be used in reply-producing-endpoint, is that true?

What documentation leads you to that conclusion? If there is something misleading in the documentation, we'd like to fix it.

See the [retry-and-more sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more#expression-evaluating-advice-demo) for an example of applying an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to an ftp outbound channel adapter.